# my jquery form submission not working

Tags: jquery, html

here is my full code just can't figure out what exactly is wrong

the head

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
```

the form

```
 <form method="post" id="ok" action="../functions/emailverification.php">
      <input type="text"  name="name" placeholder="name" />
      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="sumit" />
      <div id="success"></div>
 </form>
```

The jquery function

```
$(function ()
{
 $("#sumit").click(function(e)
 { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:  $("#ok").attr('action'),
   data: $("#ok").serialize(),
   success:function(data){
    $('#success').html()
   },
   error:function (){}
  });
 });
});
```

Somebody should please help me out

Comment: share your html code

Comment: It was wrong formated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: please help format it

Comment: What is the message you are getting in console window?

Comment: `$('#success').html()` but what html ? have you tried and used `$('#success').html(data);` ? if not empty, then `data` will return the output sent back by PHP and populated to div

Comment: reference error data is not define

Comment: check this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7uqMVEi8) : I have changed a couple of things, let us know what happens then...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the data into the success container.

```
$("#success").html(data);
```

Comment: i've tried that still not working, once i click the submit button nothing happens

Comment: add a console.log('success') and console.log('error') to the code for the success and error functions. Than you can check which one is executed.